# Installing Pantheon Desktop Environment under Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, desktop-environment, elementary-os, pantheon

I'd like to install the [Pantheon desktop environment](https://elementary.io/) (and ideally the *elementary OS* software suite) under a fresh install of Debian 11 (11.6.0 stable). There are several guides online, and a few similar questions here for older releases, however all seem to rely on the `.deb` package [described here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-on-debian), which seems to no longer be hosted. Presumably this should be relatively straightforward, however I'm not sure where to best begin.

Comment: I'd recommend you install elementary os instead. You will avoid that kind of problems.  Also that distro is Debian based (actually Ubuntu but this one is based on Debian)